# ORA-03135: connection lost contact when prepare sql from Perl

Tags: oracle, perl

I have a problem about connection to database.I execute command line as below:

```
$Oracle_Dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$two_task", $Oracle_User, $Oracle_Password, 
     { RaiseError => 0 , AutoCommit => 0, PrintError => 0});
$HNDL_TABLE = $Oracle_Dbh->prepare("select * from MMSC40_CDR where rownum<=1");
my $err="";
if(!$HNDL_TABLE){
    $err = $Oracle_Dbh->errstr;
    $exists = 0;
}

if (!$exists){
    print "error: $err";
}
```

Sometimes, it has a error occurred as below:

```
"error: ORA-03135: connection lost contact Process ID: 8936 Session ID: 1585 Serial number: 27537 (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 11 in 'select * fr<*>om MMSC40_CDR where rownum<=1')"
```

and DBA checked not have any error in listener log from database.
So if anybody can resolve or find out the cause, please tell me.

Comment: It is foolish to have both `RaiseError` and `PrintError` disabled, especially when you are having trouble with your program. That way you will get no notification of any errors that are encountered, and you will have to check for and handle all errors yourself. Disabling `AutoCommit` is also a little strange, and is normally used when you are trying to optimise working code or for advanced applications that need transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have setup to test this, but I guess you are getting this error because you have prepared the query but didn't execute it:

```
$HNDL_TABLE->execute() or die "Couldn't execute query: $Oracle_Dbh->errstr";
```

Better to use placeholder `?` in query preparation and then execute with value:

```
$HNDL_TABLE = $Oracle_Dbh->prepare("select * from MMSC40_CDR where rownum<=?");
$HNDL_TABLE->execute(1) or die "Couldn't execute query: $Oracle_Dbh->errstr";
```

Comment: oh the error is Can't call method "execute" on an undefined. But I don't know why sometimes it is run and not error

Comment: Change RaiseError value from 0 to 1, `RaiseError => 1`, it will give detailed reason why it is failing.

Comment: After i changed as you suggested, it has error "DBD::Oracle::db commit failed: ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE (DBD ERROR: OCITransCommit)"